# I have a user table with permission, I need to get the user highest role and ignore the rest of it and then insert it. into the new app

Tags: t-sql

I have this

```
Testing_296177  IntegrationRole
Testing_296177  Re-Marker
Testing_296177  AAT Conduct and Compliance
Testing_296177  AQAV Administrator
Testing_296177  AAT Assessment Team
Testing_296177  Internal Verifier
Testing_296177  External Verifier
Testing_296177  EPA Centre Administrator
Testing_296177  Membership Journey Managers - Assessment Audit
```

I need to get only assessment team roles and insert it into new table, consider I have million of records in the old app that need to migrate to new one.

Comment: Either I'm missing something, or you simply need a where clause: `select * from tableName where permissionColumnName = 'AAT Assessment Team'`

Answer (score 0):

the issue was with if the user got some highest role in old app then dont give him any other role in new app. in the old app user can have highest role along with other roles. it is a simple thing that i have done, is when is insert the record in the new app , i put not exist condition to check whether the user has the highest role, if he has then do not insert any other role for the user. Thanks everyone who has taken time to consider my question, Probably i was not clear while asking the question